# How to deny anonymous users to virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, virtual-directory

How can I deny access to my virtual directory, to those who havent logged into my asp.net website yet?

I've hooked my website up to a virtual directory setup on my server (using IIS 7).  The VD contains pdf files, that I want only logged in users to be able to access.  My problem however, is I can't seem to "deny" anonymous users from accessing the files either.  Currently, if I type the direct path to a pdf file within my virtual directory, I can access it, even if I'm not logged into my site.

I have a web.config file setup in the root of my virtual directory, which looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
   <system.web>
     <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" />
     </authentication>
     <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
   <system.web>
     <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" />
     </authentication>
     <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
        <allow users="*"/>
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

The `<deny users="?"/>`
           will deny anonymous users while `<allow users="*"/>` will allow all authenticated users
**reference : [Setting authorization rules for a particular page or folder in web.config](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx)**

Answer (score 2):

Click on your virtual directory under the IIS you have Authentication click on it and there you will be able to see Anonymous authentication disable it.