# Blazor (server side) authentication and static files

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

As per Microsoft's recommendation, I am using a custom AuthenticationStateProvider service for handling authentication/authorization for a Blazor server page.

It all works fine within razor components, where I can use the [Authorize] attribute or the AuthorizeView/Authorized/NotAuthorized tags.

Now, I wanted to serve static files outside the wwwroot folder but have control if the user is authenticated or not in order to serve the files.

**Is there a way to control access to static files served outside the wwwroot folder?**

What I found is something similar to (in program or startup):

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{    
    OnPrepareResponse = (context) =>
    {        
        if (context.Context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/MyRequestPath"))
        {
            context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-store");

            if (!context.Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                context.Context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                context.Context.Response.ContentLength = 0;
                context.Context.Response.Body = Stream.Null;
            }
        }
    },
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("PathToMyFilesOutsidewwwroot"),
    RequestPath = "/RequestPath"
    });
```

The problem with that is that is uses Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated, i.e., it uses HTTPContext, which is not available within a Blazor page (and that is why we have to use AuthenticationStateProvider).

I'd like to stick to just using Blazor best practices, and not try to circumvent it via scaffoldding, javascript, or whatever.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please define "outside the wwwroot folder".  Where do they reside?  How will you present these files to the user to access?

Comment: They reside in a different folder in the server(as it says, outside the wwwroot folder, for exmple "D:\Images"). The files are images, they could be presented as <img src=RequestPath/image.png>.

If I put values in my example:

FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("d:\\images"),
RequestPath = "/imagesoutside"

then I can use (and works OK) <img src="imagesoutside/image.png">

The problem I'm trying to address is that I have no control over whether the user has authenticated or not to access the image.

Comment: If I read this correctly you are displaying the images on pages in your Blazor App?  However you say " I have no control over whether the user has authenticated or not to access the image."  How else other than `<img src=...`  can they access (download?) images?

Comment: I think you are missing the point of the problem I'm trying to address. The point is not how the user can access the image, but rather if the person can access the resource. For example, my site can serve the image if you point to http://example.com/imagesouts/image.png, so you could create your own HTML and put <img src="http://example.com/imagesouts/image.png"> and it will show the image. What I want is to prevent anyone (if they haven't logged in) from being able to use that resource, which happens to be an static file (which resides outside of the wwwroot folder).

Comment: This is not Blazor. You'll probably  need to write your own custom `AuthenticationHandler` to handle requests to the specific paths you are using that check the header authentication information provided.

Comment: Try this, please: add a `Web.config` file into the image folder to deny anonymous access. more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14808081/4444757

Comment: in my humble opinion, although static files are stored out of wwwroot, they should be managed by another web app. That's because `example.com/imagesouts/image.png` equals to `ip:port/imagesouts/image.png`, whenever a request coming into the web app which managed the URL, you need to add authorization for it. then maybe a filter can be used in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I sticked to using the app.UseStaticFiles... approach, but in order to make it work I had to add authentication via cookies (outside of Blazor). Inside of Blazor I still use AuthenticationStateProvider, so the only thing that I had to take care is to authenticate via cookies and AuthenticationStateProvider at the same time when a user logs in. I suppose it makes sense, because authentication via cookies (prior to entering the Blazor "environment") gives me also the chance to call controllers or other pages out the razor components while still being authenticated (via cookies).